# How to get Laravel Tinker to use Heroku environment variables (config variables)?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, eloquent

I want to use Laravel Tinker to debug a database related error I'm seeing in staging and production (but not in dev on my local machine) in my Laravel 5.4 app.

Running database commands in Tinker gives errors like:

```
>>> Entry::where('updated_at', '>', 0)->get()->count()
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `entries` where `updated_at` > 0)'

>>> DB::connection()->getPdo();
PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused'
```

This is because Heroku sets environment variables from the Config Settings section of the dashboard. When I use `heroku ps:exec` to SSH into a my Heroku dyno then run `php artisan tinker`, these environment variables are not picked up for some reason and so a database connection isn't made. Is there a solution to this other than committing and pushing a .env file with the database connection details in it (very bad practice I know) ? Would be really useful to be able to debug the live (or staging) app.

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea about Heroku, but I checked the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#environment-variables) and you can see that it literally tells you it is not going to share the `environment variables`, so it is a limitation.

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes thanks, I was hoping there might be a workaround :)